# Rails Form builder select box issue arguments not passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my application, setlists have many songs and vice versa, through a model called allocations. In my form I want the user to be able to choose songs from the existing library to add to a setlist by creating a new allocation. The issue I'm having is that I want to use a multi-select box but no matter which song I pick in it, the song id gets set to 1 when it's saved. My current form is as follows:

```
<div>
  <%=nested_form_for @allocation do|builder|%>
    <%=builder.label :song_id, "Pick a song" %>

     <%= builder.hidden_field :setlist_id, value: @setlist.id %>

     <%= builder.select(:song_id, options_for_select(@selections), 
     {}, {multiple: true, size: 7}) %>

    <%= link_to "Cancel", setlist_path(@setlist), class: "btn btn-large btn-danger" %>

    <%=builder.submit "Add Song", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary", id: "addSongToSet" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This form works properly if I add ":html" to the multiple selection box, i.e.:

```
 <%= builder.select(:song_id, options_for_select(@selections), 
     {}, html: {multiple: true, size: 7}) %>
```

BUT this then changes the form back into a single dropdown box.

The rendered html when I try to use the multi select box is:

```
<select id="allocation_song_id" multiple="multiple" name="allocation[song_id][]"  size="8">
<option value="1">...</option>
<option value="2">...</option>
```

I know the issue is the line that says name= "allocation[song_id][]", where it seems to be passing a hash with an empty value. I just don't know how to fix this whilst using a multiselect box.

The @selections is being found in the controller by:

```
@selections = Song.all.collect {|s| [ [s.title, s.artist].join(" by "), s.id] }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I am using multiple select tag for selecting multiple products.

I am fetching array of products and showing as,

```
= select_tag "products", options_from_collection_for_select(@products, :id, :product_name), :multiple => true
```

So in params[:products] you will get ids of products selected.
Its working for me.